# Mount file from host machine to Docker container

Tags: docker, mount

I try to run a new container and mount files from host machine to it. I use following command:

```
docker run -v ~/home/user/:/workspace egaillardon/jmeter -n -t home/user/jmx/myjmx.jmx -l /home/user/resultado.jtl
```

After that got following error message:

> An error occurred: The file /jmeter/home/user/jmx/myjmx.jmx doesn't
>   exist or can't be opened

File exists and it can be opened.

Comment: Have you double-checked the contents of the container filesystem?  (Run the same `docker run` command, but replace the command part with an interactive shell.)  I would not expect to see a `/home/user` directory anywhere in the container filesystem with this setup; you might need to explicitly reference the `/workspace` tree instead.

Comment: @DavidMaze : I try to mount files from local host machine.

Comment: Which OS are you using?